# node q promise recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

I have a async function that returns a random student. Now I want a function that returns two unique students- the source of my problems.

```
    getTwoRandom = function(req) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();

        Q.all([
            Student.getRandom(req), 
            Student.getRandom(req)
            ])
        .then(function(students){
            if(students[0]._id !== students[1]._id) { //check unique
                deferred.resolve(students);
            } else {
                //students are the same so try again... this breaks
                return getTwoRandom(req);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

then further down I have something like this:

```
getTwoRandom(req).then(function(students) {
     //do what I want...
});
```

The problem is when I do `return getTwoRandom(req);` the `.then()` function down the lines doesnt fire... is this returning a different promise that `.then()` isnt using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've over-complicated it quite a bit :)

You can do it like this instead:

```
getTwoRandom = function(req) {
    return Q.all([
        Student.getRandom(req), 
        Student.getRandom(req)
    ]).then(function(students) {
        if(students[0]._id !== students[1]._id) {
            return students;
        } else {
            return getTwoRandom(req);
        }
    });
};
```

Now, why does this work? The result of `Q.all` is always a new promise (no need to create a new deferred). Whatever value you return (ike `students`) will be wrapped in this new promise. If instead an actual promise is returned (like `getTwoRandom(req)`), then that promise will be returned. Which sounds like what you wanted to do.

Comment: Confused b/c this isnt returning a promise for me to use later down the line...? What would the subsequent code look like?

Comment: What do you mean? It absolutely returns a promise. Like I described above, `Q.all` returns a promise and we're returning that.

Comment: Further down you would use it exactly like you described yourself.

Comment: It says "Cannot call method 'then' of undefined"

Comment: Or well, my description was a bit off.. the result of `Q.all` is passed to `then` and the result of `then` (the two students) are returned when the function ends. Maybe it becomes more clear if I split it up a little.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the "return" in the beginning of the function.